# How to persist Joda LocalDateTime in Android SQLite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, jodatime

I need to persist Joda LocalDateTime in SQLite database on Android.
SQLite does not have date specific date data types, [instead TEXT and INTEGER is suggested](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). 
How can I safely convert Joda LocalDateTime into milliseconds (long) and back for persisting and reading to/from the database ?
I'm concerned about loosing the time zone.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm ZZ");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-01-18 22:36 -06:00", formatter);
long milliseconds = ... ?
```

Comment: You don't need to be concerned about loosing the timezone when you convert a `LocalDateTime` to a long. You have already lost the zone during parsing in first step. Keep in mind that a `LocalDateTime` does not track the zone (despite the sometimes confusing name prefix "Local").

Comment: @MenoHochschild You didn't answer the question.